# Resolve GROUP BY SQL more efficiently SQL Server AdventureWorks

Tags: sql-server, sum, max, min, adventureworks

Im looking the most efficient way to resolve this.

I have to create a Query SQL using AdventureWorks database. This Query SQL must return the fields As shown below

```
declare @fecha datetime
set @fecha = GETDATE()-1365
declare @MPid int
set @MPid = 50

select OH.CustomerID, OH.SalesPersonID, 
'Month' = Month(OH.OrderDate), 
PP.Name, 
pp.MakeFlag, 
'CantProduct' = SUM(SOD.OrderQty), 
'MinUnitPrice' = 0 , 
'MaxUnitPrice' = 0 

from sales.SalesOrderHeader OH JOIN sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD ON OH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
JOIN Production.Product PP ON SOD.ProductID = PP.ProductID
where OH.OrderDate > DATEADD(year,-1,@fecha) and pp.ProductID > @MPid 
group by OH.CustomerID, OH.SalesPersonID, Month(OH.OrderDate), PP.Name, pp.MakeFlag
```

[An example of the results](http://sites.google.com/site/martinaguirre77/arcon/ima1.png)

Instead of MinUnitPrice and MaxUnitPrice equal to 0, should obtain the maximum and minimum prices.
Can it be resolved without using temporary tables? Or which would be the most efficient solution?
Thanks

Comment: Just use the `MAX` and `MIN` aggregate functions, _exactly_ as you have used the `SUM` aggregate function

Comment: Thanks but that way the maximum and minimum values ​​are always the same and not the ones that are required

Comment: There is no explanation of what you're actually after. _obtain the maximum and minimum prices._ min and max of what? Do you want the max/min prices for a salesperson? or a salesperson / customer combination? Please explain what you want.

Comment: Thanks again for responding. I have solved the rest. I only need the maximum and minimum price amounts in the periods consulted. Could you see the ling to the capture ?

Comment: So you want the max and min found for `OrderDate after  DATEADD(year,-1,@fecha)`, which will be the same number for every row right?

Comment: I want the maximum and minimum price charged in that time period for each product grouped by month, SalesPersonId and by CustomerID

Comment: So your expected figures will repeat across different `MakeFlag` rows, correct? Do you really need `MakeFlags` there? Do many products have different `MakeFlags`?

Comment: MakFlag Belongs to the Production.Product table so you should not have different values. They are unique by product.

Comment: Then just plugging in `MAX` and `MIN` in as I suggested should give you what you want. Did you try it? Can you post what you see and explain why it is incorrect? You should not be seeing values that are "always the same"

Comment: I think i have it

Comment: Note that it's going to aggregate across the years. i.e. month 6 is June across _all_ years

Comment: Good observation about the months of different years

Comment: In future can you clearly describe what you're after - if you look through your question and comments, communication is pretty terrible here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution

```
declare @fecha datetime
declare @MPid int

set @fecha = GETDATE()-1365
set @MPid = 50


select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OH.CustomerID ASC) AS ID, OH.CustomerID, OH.SalesPersonID, 'Month' = Month(OH.OrderDate),PP.Name, pp.MakeFlag, 'CantProduct' = SUM(SOD.OrderQty), 
'MinUnitPrice' = min(SOD3.MinUnitPrice) , 'MaxUnitPrice' = max(SOD5.MaxUnitPrice)

from sales.SalesOrderHeader OH Join sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD ON OH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
    Join Production.Product PP ON SOD.ProductID = PP.ProductID

    Join ( select SOD2.ProductID, SOD2.SalesOrderID, 'MinUnitPrice' = Min(SOD2.UnitPrice) from sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD2 
            group by SOD2.ProductID ,SOD2.SalesOrderID ) SOD3 ON SOD3.ProductID = SOD.ProductID and  SOD3.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID

    Join ( select SOD4.ProductID, SOD4.SalesOrderID, 'MaxUnitPrice' = Max(SOD4.UnitPrice) from sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD4 
            group by SOD4.ProductID ,SOD4.SalesOrderID ) SOD5 ON SOD5.ProductID = SOD.ProductID and  SOD5.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID

    where OH.OrderDate > DATEADD(year,-1,@fecha) and pp.ProductID > @MPid

    group by OH.CustomerID, OH.SalesPersonID, Month(OH.OrderDate), PP.Name, pp.MakeFlag
```